# how to determine if javascript module was imported or loaded via script src?

Tags: javascript, browser, es6-modules

Suppose I have a module named `module.js`:

```js
export default function greet() { console.info( 'hello' ); }
```

Within `module.js` (either inside or outside of function `greet`), how can I determine whether the module was loaded using:

```html
<script type=module src="./module.js">
```

versus:

```html
<script type=module>
import greet from './module.js';
</script>
```

Either way, `import.meta` is the same, `document.currentScript` is `null`, and NodeJS's `require` (and therefore `require.main`) and `module` are both `undefined`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import any module (either using `import`  or `<script type="module">`), the body of the module will be evaluated only once, even if you import that module from multiple places.

So, the following:

```js
//module.js
console.log('I was imported')
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import './module.js'
</script>
<script type="module" src="./module.js"></script>
```

...will log `I was imported` only once.

From that, we can clearly see that a module may be imported multiple ways *at the same time*, so there **can not be** any way to determine the way how a module was imported...

...as long as you don't use exports.

Including a module using a script tag is identical to the `import 'modulepath'` syntax, that is, [in MDN's words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only), *importing a module for its side effects only*.

That means, that no exports are taken, the module is just evaluated.

However, if one of the exports is used (called, for example) you can rule out the possibility that the module's instance that used the export was imported by a script tag.

The following scenario is still possible, though:

```js
//module.js
export default function greet() { 
  console.info('hello'); //<-- This must have been called from an `import` import
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import greet from './module.js';
  greet()  //imported by `import`
</script>
<script type="module" src="./module.js"></script> <!-- imported by script tag -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Based on you (accurate & accepted) answer, I realize that I didn't ask the question I really should have. I'll appreciate if you know the answer to my new question!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797713/how-to-programmatically-determine-within-the-module-if-javascript-module-was-l