# how to programmatically determine, within the module, if javascript module was loaded via script src (not imported)

Tags: javascript, browser, es6-modules

Suppose I have a module:

```js
// module.js
export default function greet() { console.info( 'hello' ); }
```

If the module is loaded via:

```html
<script type=module>
import greet from './module.js';
...
</script>
```

then I want the calling code to be able to invoke `greet()` on its own, without it being called automatically (the normal scenario).

However, if the module is loaded via:

```html
<script type=module src="./module.js"></script>
```

then I want the module to invoke `greet()` immediately (as a side-effect of being loaded).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this question has a similar answer to your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61790963/8376184): it isn't possible.

Modules may export things, but they aren't responsible for how (and which) do the importers use (of) them.

Modules are created to be separate and **reusable**, even on the same page, without re-evaluation:

The module's code evaluated once, then its exports are passed to every place that imports it.

That design is good, but essentially makes impossible for a module to determine *anything* about its importers.

---

On the other hand, the `<script type="module">` syntax also wasn't designed for that: it's the way to signal the browser through HTML the *main* (aka. "*top-level*") module,  that loads its dependecies (sub-modules) on its own.

---

Partial solution:

Make a *single* top-level module, that imports everything else and operates the page by "side effects", and avoid importing other modules by script tags. Moreover, I recommend you to avoid side effects in the non-top-level modules, and focus on exports instead.

And if someone really wants to import your module from their HTML, they can still do this instead:

```html
<script type="module">
  import greet from './module.js';
  greet();
</script>
```

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer but I hoped someone might know a secret I couldn't find anywhere else. :-p Thank you!