# How to detect an ES module imported in the browser?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a script meant to be imported in the browser. It can be used in two ways, either as a regular `<script src="...">` or as an ES module.

I would like it to behave differently depending on whether it was `import`ed or loaded as a `<script>`.

Is it possible to detect either at runtime?

Comment: check <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790963/how-to-determine-if-javascript-module-was-imported-or-loaded-via-script-src>

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `document.currentScript` inside your script. Imported modules don't support it.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more neat way but a functional workaround can be to read the document and see if script tag with certain `src` exists or not.